# Profile:edit - exp:profile:reset_password - form redirects to index.php

Tags: profile-edit, forgot-password, mightybigrobot

When using the latest release of Profile:edit (Mighty Big Robot module) I get redirected to 
the homepage when any template contains the reset pass form:

```
{exp:profile:reset_password return="profile/reset_confirmed"}
        <fieldset>
            <label>New Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" value="">
            <label>New Password Confirm</label>
            <input type="password" name="password_confirm" value="">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </fieldset>
    {/exp:profile:reset_password}
```

I've tested as member/admin and under clean cache/cookie situation but I can't get the loop to complete - always redirects (the URLs are definitely correct).

Anyone there from Mighty Big Robot to help? Or another developer who's seen similar?

EE v2.7.3

Ta.

Comment: What version of EE are you using?

Comment: V. 2.7.3 - updated OP.

Comment: I'm also seeing this. Was there ever any updates for this by chance?

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on a EE 2.7.0 site that uses the latest Profile:edit and has this password reset form, and I've **never** seen the issue you're describing.

If this were happening on just one page, I'd say that it sounds like maybe you have EE access restrictions set on your Reset Password page, with the restriction's "unauthorized" redirect pointing to the site homepage. Have you checked for this in the EE Template Manager?

If it's happening on multiple pages, and on pages with no EE access restrictions, then I don't know what's up -- again, I've never seen this issue.

*updated: added the EE version.*

Comment: What version of EE are you using on the site that doesn't exhibit this problem?

Comment: The site is EE 2.7.0.

Comment: I checked that. Template doesn't have redirect/restriction (was logged in as admin anyway). We're on a later version of EE, so could be something to do with it?

Comment: I'm not sure when/if it changed, but I'm almost certain that there has been a recent modification of how EE handles password resets. The changelog (http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html) doesn't mention a switch, but that might not mean anything. :-)